# Stacked divs with angled borders and bg images

Tags: jquery, css, transform

Essentially I need multiple divs (width:100% and fixed height, 300-400px), stacked vertically each with an angled border (alternating angles top and bottom).  The container will also need background images.  Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

```
    <style type="text/css">
body,html,h1{margin:0;}
.wrap{overflow:hidden;}
.one,.two,.three {height: 400px;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;position:relative;}
.uno,.dos,.tres{height: 100%;position:relative;}
.uno{background:url('img/one.jpg') no-repeat 0 0 scroll transparent;}
.dos{background:url('img/two.jpg') no-repeat 0 0 scroll transparent;}
.tres{background:url('img/three.jpg') no-repeat 0 0 scroll transparent;}
.box{height:400px;}

</style>
<div class="wrap">

    <div class="box uno">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>


    <div class="box dos">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>


    <div class="box tres">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you define "angled border"?   A picture of your intended layout would go a long way here

Comment: And an example of what he currently has.

Comment: Sure..  here's an example:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/sae8vxloud0wcel/angles.jpg?dl=0  Thanks.  I could do this with static images, but I really need to do with css and/or js.  Would be best if they were background images of the containers.